# Comment upvotes aren't removed when the vote owner's account is deleted

Tags: bug, comments, voting, up-votes, deleted-accounts

I recently realized by accident that, when deleting your account, your comment upvotes are not removed, unlike up/down votes. Just as an example, I posted [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366883/how-do-i-open-exe-in-ubuntu-without-wine-or-any-other-windows-compatibility-lay#comment1856650_366883) comment on a site where I didn't previously have an account, and upvoted it 10 times by deleting and recreating my account (hopefully that's not considered abuse because I was testing a bug on a useless comment).

Supposedly, all votes are supposed to be removed when the owner's account is deleted (except in the case of high reputation users). Is it intentional that comment votes are kept? If so, why?

Comment: Even if they do get removed (I've no idea if they are), there's nothing that ever runs to normalize comment scores. There is no scheduled task that looks through all the comment votes and corrects scores to the current count, and when you vote on a comment it doesn't check other votes - it just takes the current score and adds 1. Comment votes deleted outside the normal "this user manually retracted the vote" would never *decrement* the score.

Comment: Hm, I checked the deletion function. It does just flat-out delete any comment votes the user has cast (doesn't set the DeletionDate, literally deletes them from the database). So the problem is simply that this denormalized number is never updated.

Comment: @animuson is that something likely to be fixed/changed? It seems to me that, if the score is updated, it may as well be shown as being changed as well to accurately reflect what the actual score is.

Comment: *shrugs* Depends on if someone actually cares enough to make the change. It'd likely have to be another scheduled task to make sure all possible cases are accounted for, so it's more convincing someone that comment scores are important enough to run that query every day. I'm not sure they really are.